# Merge dataframes within an ordered list

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I had a dictionary of dataframes (**opdict**) that I sorted according to its key values. This gave me a list of tuples (**oplist**), with the tuples containing two elements: Index 0 with key values of opdict and Index 1 with the values (dataframes) of opdict. My question is, how do I merge all the dataframes within oplist to **a single dataframe** (**opdf**) row by row i.e. first stack together all the first rows of all dataframes within oplist, then stack together all the second rows of all dataframes within oplist and so on. I have a feeling that pandas.concat or pandas.join is the way to go, but I am not sure of the correct code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the example with some data. Probably df.merge and seting axis parameter would require here.

Comment: Is there any way you could simply concatenate them the normal way, and reorder the rows afterwards?

Comment: @AMC: exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of tuples to list of DataFrames:

```
list_of_dfs = [i[1] for i in oplist]
```

Concatenate, then sort by the index:

```
concat_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs).sort_index()
```

Comment: I got it to work by slightly modifying your second line of code:
`concat_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs).sort_index(kind='merge')`